# Unsupported Media Type Jersey

Tags: json, maven, jersey

I am using Maven and Jersey on Tomcat7 to build a web server, but I keep getting a 415 response. My request is made using Postman and Advanced Rest Client

My stubbed method:

```
@POST
@Path("/createuser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUser(UserInformation user){
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Custom class:

```
package efile.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserInformation {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Request:

{myhost}/createuser

Headers:

accept: application/json

content-type: application/json

Request body:

```
{
"id":"1234567",
"userName":"qwer",
"password":"zxcv",
"firstName":"jasdfme",
"lastName":"qwetad",
"emailAddress": "qwet@gf4elk.com"
}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
    <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does your {myhost} above contain the context of your application and any path portion defined in your servlet mapping (or @ApplicationPath annotation)?

Comment: How did you configure that Jackson shall be used for JSON marshalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue after modifying the dependencies in the pom.xml. I updated the jersey dependencies to 1.18.1 and added the fasterxml json provider dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My guess is that it was just the json-provider dependency that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On my side it was because I forgot to add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

after

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

No warnings/errors at compilation but 415 Unsuported Media Type at runtime trying to consum JSON on Jersey 2.18 running on AppEngine
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the 'Accept' header, you may also need to add the @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) annotation to your method, or, remove the Accept header from the request if you are not expecting a response body.

Edit:

Ok... After a bit of experimentation, I believe I have been able to reproduce your problem and find a solution.

I see from your pom file that you are using Jersey 1.17.  I reproduced your problem using Jersey 1.18, but I suspect it is equally valid for 1.17.  It appears that Jersey does not come with Jackson support built in, but Jackson must be installed as a provider.  I've always used it with containers like Glassfish where the providers come pre-configured.

I was not able to make Jersey 1.18 work with the latest Jackson 2 libraries (under the com.fasterxml.jackson groupId) that you were pulling in with your pom.xml, but I was able to get it working with the older Jackson libraries when the groupId was still org.codehaus.jackson.  It appears that Jersey 1.18 uses a class called com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy which looks specifically for a Jackson implementation in org.codehaus.jackson... So you might not be able to make the newer versions of Jackson work without upgrading to a newer version of Jersey.

Firstly, I added the XmlRootElement annotation to the UserInformation class.  Jax-RS will serialize and deserialize JAXB objects and this annotation marks this class as a JaxB object. This required an additional dependency in the pom on the jaxb-api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Next, I removed all of the Jersey dependencies from your pom.xml file, and added a dependency on the jersey-server to give access to the necessary JaxRS annotations:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I then took a clean installation of Tomcat 7.0.52, and added the following jars to the CATALINA_HOME/lib directory:

- **asm-3.3.1.jar** (Byte code manipulation used by Jackson)
- **jacksore-core-asl-1.9.13.jar** (Includes the Jackson JSON Provider)
- **jersey-bundle-1.18.jar** (The Jersey Implementation)

I found it necessary to add these jars to the Tomcat lib folder rather than include them in the project WAR file.  I don't work with Tomcat much, so I don't recall the rules about exactly when it is necessary to place jars in the Tomcat lib directory vs. including them in the WAR file.

Following all of those steps I was able to go from getting the 415 Media Unsupported error to a 200 OK on the POST.

I hope this helps.

Comment: While you do submit a valid style point, neither of those resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't recall what JSON parser Jersey uses, but it also might be picky over the fact that your casing of 'username' is different between your POJO and your JSON body.  Regarding the Consumes and Produces headers, I know RestEasy can get very picky about them, so it's not necessarily a pure stylistic issue (although I know your not using RestEasy).  Sorry it didn't fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, and good catch on the case issue. Generally I do find that Jersey is case-sensitive, and I previously had been using a version of code that used 'userName', so when I modified my code I forgot to change it. Generally, though, Jersey will give a very specific error message (no exact example right now, but something like "username not marked ignorable"), so I think there's a bigger underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time on it. It was your answer that lead me to the solution I found.